# Verifying Compounded Interest Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have used a Compounded Interest Formula to calculate the total amount after a year.

100000 invested on Jan 1st 2021 yields **5% every 2 weeks**. So the total would be 355567.27 on Jan 1st 2022.

Is my calculation correct?

This is what I did.

[image]

Comment: Is this consistent with the customary number format system in question? i.e. would appear first comma misplaced/indicates million as opposed to hundreds of thousands - no (not sure- just asking; presumably automatically formatted like this in Excel)...

Comment: Yes this is how it works in Indian Currency system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if it is really compounding 5% every two weeks.

Outside the scope of the question, but I find the FV formula in Excel does not simplify things. It would be easier for me to do `=100000*(1.05)^26`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, calc. is correct per following screenshot/function:

[image: Direct calc. method]

```
=C4*(1+C5)^C6
```

---

I'd say it's a great return given this equates to an effective annual rate of interest =  ~256%:

[image: Effective annual rate]

```
=(1+C5)^C6-1
```

---

Notes: 26 calculated as follows:

[image: Number of 2 week periods (2021)]

```
=(DATE(2022,1,1)-1-DATE(2021,1,1))/14
```

Comment: Great Insights. Wish I could mark two answers but I upvoted you. Cheers, and yes returns are pretty good (3-5% every fortnight) when your money is in the Stock market.